# Unexpected Behavior with DBConcurrencyException Handler

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error when catching DBConcurrecyExceptions on a vb.net Windows form that displays the contents from several different tables from the underlying database. These different tables are related by creating relationships in the dataset containing these tables. For example, the relationship to relate the "POs" table to the "primary" table "Jobs" is created with the following code:

`DS.Relations.Add("RPO", DS.Tables("Jobs").Columns("ID"), DS.Tables("POs").Columns("JobID"), False)`

Note that the child constraint in this relationship is set to False.

Because this app is multi-user, I have added a Catch to trap any DBConcurrencyExceptions immediately after the "Update" method of the dataadapter is called, as follows:

`Catch DBEX As DBConcurrencyException`

The first line after the exception uses the primary key value of the row that caused this exception to retrieve that same row from the underlying database:

```
Dim TmpTbl As DataTable = GetDBRow("POs", "RecID", DBEX.Row.Item("RecID"))
```

Where the primary key value of the row that caused the exception is retrieved from DBEX.Row.Item("RecID"). However, in a few isolated cases, the value in DBEX.Row.Item("RecID") returns a Null value, so the retrieval of the offending datarow from the underlying database table fails and the update is lost (i.e. the users changes to that table are not saved to the underlying database table).

I have confirmed that the underlying table's, in this case "POs", primary key is set to the column "RecID" and that column cannot and does not contain any null values. So how can that column in the DBEX exception row have a value of Null? Could the fact that I am not setting the child constraint in the relationship of that table be a factor?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Larry

Comment: just a suggestion - doing complicated stuff (like further updates, database access) in a `Catch` is probably just bad idea since you might have more problems inside that code - keep the catches simple.

Comment: Note that as currently implemented, `GetDBRow` is potentially hazardous in the event of an exception since it only calls `ErrorReporter` and otherwise eats the exception.